# Is it secure to connect to a remote Windows Server using Remote Desktop only?

Tags: operating-systems, authentication, windows, remote-desktop, remote-server

I have a Windows Server that I login to from my home. I only use the pre-installed Remote Desktop. Is this a secure way to remote login or should I improve it in some way? If I should improve it, please describe how it is more secure that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using SSL, see this [technote](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx) for details.

In particular, it is important to set up your security layers

> The three available security layers are:
>
> **SSL (TLS 1.0) SSL (TLS 1.0)**
>
> will be used for server authentication and for encrypting all data
>   transferred between the server and the client.
>
> **Negotiate**
>
> The most
>   secure layer that is supported by the client will be used. If
>   supported, SSL (TLS 1.0) will be used. If the client does not support
>   SSL (TLS 1.0), the RDP Security Layer will be used. This is the
>   default setting.
>
> **RDP Security Layer**
>
> Communication between the server
>   and the client will use native RDP encryption. If you select RDP
>   Security Layer, you cannot use Network Level Authentication.

And the Encryption Level:

> **Low**
>
> Data sent from the client to the server is encrypted using 56-bit
>   encryption. Data sent from the server to the client is not encrypted.
>
> **Client Compatible** Encrypts client/server communication at the maximum
>   key strength supported by the client. Use this level when the terminal
>   server is running in an environment containing mixed or legacy
>   clients. This is the default encryption level.
>
> **High** Encrypts
>   client/server communication using 128-bit encryption. Use this level
>   when the clients accessing the terminal server also support 128-bit
>   encryption. When encryption is set at this level, clients that do not
>   support this level of encryption will not be able to connect.
>
> **FIPS**
>   **Compliant** All client/server communication is encrypted and decrypted
>   with the Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS) encryption
>   algorithms. FIPS 140-1 (1994) and its successor, FIPS 140-2 (2001),
>   describe U.S. government requirements for encryption.

Comment: If you could update this answer with some bullet point highlights it would be much more valuable, and would likely get more upvotes. As it stands, its value as a link is low and it may get deleted.