# CVE-2018-0886 mitigation for an unpatchable RDP server

Tags: certificates, known-vulnerabilities, rdp

An up-to-date Windows 10 client is connecting to a Windows 10 RDP host which is stuck at 1511 (host can't be updated and 1511 is out of support for receiving patches such as the CVE-2018-0886 mitigation).

What exactly is the exposure going over public internet? Is there another way to mitigate the exposure other than installing a software patch?

Specifically: my understanding is that CVE-2018-0886 requires a man-in-the-middle setup to initiate an attack. If the client and host are both connected to trusted providers, does it still leave an opportunity for a MITM (intermediate nodes between the providers)?

Also: when initiating an RDP connection, there is often a prompt to accept a certificate (as shown in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66466/what-security-risks-do-you-face-when-connecting-to-a-server-via-rdp)), and it seems to re-appear from time to time between the same pair of client and host. This suggests to me that the RDP host is generating and periodically re-generating a self-signed certificate, which seems to me to be the point at which a MITM can insert itself. Is there any procedure by which the host can generate a long-lived certificate (even if self-signed) which can be transferred to a client (by secure connection) so that the trust relationship is maintained (no prompt to trust a self-signed cert over a questionable connection)? And, in doing this, does it not mitigate the CVE-2018-0886 vulnerability without having to do any patching?

Comment: Some interesting links: 1. Blog with [short video](https://blog.preempt.com/security-advisory-credssp). 2. More [detailed blog](https://blog.preempt.com/how-we-exploited-the-authentication-in-ms-rdp). 3. [16 page white paper](https://www.preempt.com/wp-content/uploads/White_paper_CredSSP.pdf). 4. [41min long video from BH Asia 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9W-8oKHheI).

Comment: NAA, but you could try a service like this: https://0patch.com/

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. You're asking "how do I fix the fact that my server is unsafe, without patching it", but the question that you actually need to have answered is "how do I fix the fact that I can't patch my server".

Answer (score 1):

**Require the client to log into a VPN** before connecting to the server. Expose the RDP port only to hosts connected through the VPN.

This will protect you not only from CVE-2018-0886 but also from other RDP vulnerabilities, such as CVE-2019-0708 (BlueKeep) and those that *will continue appearing* in the future, **if** no malicious actor is able to get into the VPN.

Please note this is a big if. Even the computer from which the most trusted user might get compromised, you should really require a VPN *and* patch the vulnerabilities. But missing the later one, at least you should implement the former.

Answer (score 0):

Certs aren't going to save you.  The only mitigation I'm aware of are the patches.

Allow me to quote from the folks who discovered this CVE:
https://blog.preempt.com/how-we-exploited-the-authentication-in-ms-rdp

---

*Exploiting the NTLM relay vulnerability was possible because of the way RDP is implemented. Let's take a look at the process:*

1. *Negotiation over capabilities (Usually CredSSP is chosen)*
2. *TLS is established*
3. *Network Layer Authentication (NLA) is carried out using
   CredSSP*
4. *The client verifies the certificate, displaying warning if
   needed*

---

Credentials are sent in step 3 listed above, and the cert is verified in step 4.  Ouch.  This means that a certificate-based enforcement is too late  - by the time you realize the cert is wrong, you have already sent credentials.

Not sure what's going on with the certificate re-prompt.